# generator expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, generators

Boas, tenho estado a tentar optimizar o meu código e encontrei generator expressions, só que não estou a entender nada daquilo.

Por exemplo:

```
for mCp in mWithoutNone:
    for ctt in moradasCTT:
        if mCp[3] == ctt[3]:
            mWithCp4.append( ctt )
        else:
            pass
```

e queria por do tipo:

```
for mCp in mWithoutNone: # necessito mesmo deste for aqui por causa de uns if que tenho mais a frente
    mCp[3] == ctt[3] if mWithCp4.append( ctt ) else '' for ctt in moradasCTT
```

Codigo completo: https://pastebin.com/WtD6XbVT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([TL;DR](https://repl.it/JOcy/0))
 
Expressões geradoras, ou genexp é um assunto bem amplo no python, mas talvez o que vc precisa seja das list comprehensions ou listcomps, vou tentar dar um exmplo aqui usando a abordagem, com `for`, com liscomps e uma pequena amostra das genexps.

Digamos que tenhamos uma lista de números:

```
[1,2,5,10,20,4,5,7.18,55,34,14,44,89,70,64]
```

e precisamos extrair da mesma somente os divisiveis por 2. A primeira opção seria:

**Abordagem com for:**

```
lst1 = [1,2,5,10,20,4,5,7.18,55,34,14,44,89,70,64]
lst2 = []

for number in lst1:
  if number%2==0:
    lst2.append(number)
```

**Output:**

```
print (lst2)
[2, 10, 20, 4, 34, 14, 44, 70, 64]
```

Agora vamos ver como ficaria usando listcomps.

### Usando listcomps:

```
## Usando listcomps ##
listcomps1 = [number for number in lst1 if number%2==0]
```

**Output:**

```
 print('listcomps1 (listcomps) :',listcomps1,'\n')
 listcomps1 (listcomps) : [2, 10, 20, 4, 34, 14, 44, 70, 64]
```

**Utilizando genexp:**

```
## Usando Expressões geradoras ##
gen1 = (number for number in lst1 if number%2==0)
```

Veja que para gerar a explressão geradora, a sintax é identica à geração da listcomps, a única diferença é o uso de parenteses ao invés de colchetes, mas vamos ver o resultado:

**output:**

```
print('gen1 (genexp) : ', gen1,'\n')
gen1 (genexp) :  <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb9f4d705c8>
```

Veja que o resultado não foi uma lista e sim um `objeto`, este objeto poderá ser 'manipulado' de várias formas, poderiamos fazer, por exemplo:

```
print (list(gen1))
```

E obteriamos como resultado exatamente o que obtemos com listcomp, ou seja,  `[2, 10, 20, 4, 34, 14, 44, 70, 64]`, porém 'matariamos' a expressão geradora e o resultado do próximo exemplo geraria um erro.

**Apresentando o quinto elemento da genexp:**

Levando em consideração que, no código, não incluimos o comando do tópico anteiror `print (list(gen1))`, poderiamos apresentar um elemento qualquer da genexp sem criar uma lista inteira.

```
## Apresentando o 5 elemento da gen1?
print ('Quinto elemento: ', list(gen1)[5], '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Quinto elemento:  14
```

**Mostrando que a genexp "morreu" depois de executada:**

```
## Mostrando que a gen1 foi executada e "morreu": ##
print ('O que aconteceu com gen1: ', list(gen1))
```

**Output:**

```
O que aconteceu com gen1:  []
```

**Então qual é a vantagem das genexps?**
 
A vantagem principal das genexps é que elas não criam, a priori, uma lista inteira na memoria. claro que em exemplos como os apresentados aqui, não existem vantagens significativas, mas, suponha que no exemplo acima a fonte não seja uma lista interna e sim algum artefato externo (um banco de dados, por exemplo) com milhares ou milões de elementos, e a necessidade fosse acessar elementos especificos na resultante (como o quinto elemento, do exemplo), nesse caso, voce teria como resultante somente a genexp e não a lista inteira. Claro que a explanação foi minimalista, para uma visão mais ampla, consulte a [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#references).

[Execute o codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JOcy/0)

Answer (score 1):

generator expressions tem uma sintaxe simples:

```
(expressão for variavel in interavel if condição)
```

caso queira todos os valores, pode omitir a condição, dai fica:

```
(expressão, for variavel in iteravel)
```

ambos são equivalentes a:

```
def generator():
    for variavel in iteravel:
        if condição:
            yield expressão #poderia ser: variavel + 1.5 por exemplo
```

Vou fazer um exemplo em portugol e python

```
para cada numero entre 0 e 100 selecione os numeros divisiveis por 2
```

poderia ser traduzido em python como:

```
>>> [numero for numero in range(0, 101) if numero % 2 == 0]
retorna:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100]
```

isso na verdade é uma lista e não um generator por causa dos colchetes.
porem se substituir os colchetes por parenteses isso se torna um generator object que apenas contem a expressão mas não guarda todos os valores em uma lista, voce pode interar normalmente sobre ele mas não pode acessar indices pois ele não armazena dados.

```
#criando gerador
>>> gerador = (numero for numero in range(0, 101) if numero % 2 == 0)
>>> gerador
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02DDF240>
#interando sobre ele
>>> for x in gerador:
    print(x)

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
...
#tentando acessar um indice falha pois geradores não são listas
>>> gerador[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    gerador[10]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```