# Imprimir em ordem crescente os n primeiros naturais que são múltiplos de i ou de j ou de ambos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dados n e dois números inteiros positivos i e j diferentes de 0,
imprimir em ordem crescente os n primeiros naturais que são múltiplos de i ou
de j e ou de ambos.

Exemplo: Para n = 6 , i = 2 e j = 3 a saída deverá ser : 0,2,3,4,6,8.

```
n = int(input("Digite n: "))

i = int(input("Digite i: "))

j = int(input("Digite j: "))

lista = []

for k in range(i,i+1):
    for l in range(0,n):
        print("{}*{} = {}".format(k,l,k*l))
        lista.append(k*l)



for k in range(j,j+1):
    for l in range(0,n):
        print("{}*{} = {}".format(k,l,k*l))
        lista.append(k*l)


print(lista)
```

O programa acima com n =6, i =2 e j=3 está dando como saída:

[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

Para a saída ser correta, eu precisaria ordenar a lista acima em ordem crescente, exluindo os valores duplicados:

[0,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,15]

e depois pegar os 6 primeiros valores, ficando: [0,2,3,4,6,8], que é a saída esperada.

Alguma ideia de como melhorar/corrigir o programa acima?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se só precisas de uma lista com `n` números porquê a sobrecarga de adicionar mais e depois retira-los desnecessáriamente?

Podes usar um ciclo while e o modulo para ver se algum dos nums `i` e `j` é multiplo de cada número:

```
n = 6
i = 2
j = 3

nat_nums, x = [], 0
while len(nat_nums) < n: # enquanto a a nossa lista tiver menos que `n` elementos
    if(x%i == 0 or x%j == 0): # modulo para ver se e multiplo de algum ou ambos
        nat_nums.append(x) # adicionar `x` a nossa lista
    x += 1

print(nat_nums) # [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/VVuURF)

Utilizando uma função e um [*generator*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218091/generator-expressions/218150#218150):

```
def get_multis(n, i, j):
    x = 0
    while n > 0:
        if(x%i == 0 or x%j == 0): # modulo para ver se e multiplo de algum ou ambos
            yield x
            n -= 1
        x += 1

n, i, j = 6, 2, 3
print(list(get_multis(n, i, j))) # [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/sa9QEl)

PS: desta maneira já vem ordenada.

Comment: Ficou ótimo! Obrigado!

Comment: sua solução é excelente mas só a nível de aprendizado, como eu poderia terminar a solucao do jeito que eu comecei, ou seja, ordenando [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15] e excluindo os repetido? É possível?

Comment: @EdS, para excluir todos a partir do nº elemento, no teu caso é só `sorted(set(lista))[:n]`, https://ideone.com/HpqHGu, https://ideone.com/DTJnr7

Comment: Eu tentei:   lista= [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15] e não deu certo: lista.sort(key=int) saiu [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15], ou seja não ordenou... O que houve?

Comment: @EdS, coloquei o melhor a fazer no comentário acima, `key=int` foi o problema, isso não está a fazer nada

Comment: Muito obrigado! Embora o meu algoritmo seja totalmente ineficiente, eu precisava entender como teminá-lo! Agora sim! Você sugere alguma lista de exercícios para eu treinar?

Comment: @EdS isso não falta: https://www.google.pt/search?q=python+exercises&oq=python+exer&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.3141j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 , https://www.google.pt/search?ei=0uq0WsaiDYy5UY_gg5AE&q=exerc%C3%ADcios+de+python&oq=exerc%C3%ADcios+de+python&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l8.18798.24184.0.24916.20.15.0.5.5.0.132.1079.10j2.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.17.1088...35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1.0.OA7iF72CAZo