# Funções geradoras: Quais as vantagens em utilizá-las?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generators

Função geradora:

```
def geraQuadrados(n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i**2



    for i in geraQuadrados(5):
        print(i)
```

sem função geradora:

```
def novosQuadrados(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(i**2)
    return l

for i in novosQuadrados(5):
    print(i)
```

Os códigos com o uso de função geradora e sem a função geradora têm a mesma saída. Existe alguma vantagem em utilizar função geradora/yield?

Eu ainda acho confusa a cláusula yield!

Comment: Acho que pode ser relacionada e talvez duplicada de alguma destas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218091/generator-expressions/218150#218150, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92921/para-que-serve-o-yield/92925#92925, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191752/como-funciona-o-yield-no-javascript/191780#191780 ... Esse útimo link não é python mas a resposta explica bem o que são/vantagens. Uma grande vantagem é não ocuparem espaço (muito pouco) em memória, especialmente quando é um grande conjunto de dados que só vai ser consumido (usado) uma vez, é escusado andar com ele atrás

Comment: Se minha resposta satisfez sua pergunta, por favor marque-a como correta.

Answer (score 2):

De uma forma muito básica, geradores são preguiçosos, isto é, o próximo elemento a ser "cuspido" será processado assim que pedido, diferente de uma lista onde todos os elementos são processados e ficam em memória.

Outra diferença é que o gerador só pode ser percorrido uma vez, se tentar acessá-lo após chegar no final, recebera a exçeção `StopIteration`.